# Difference between normal firebase and firebase admin sdk

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Just have a small doubt, I am building a small application in python which will use firebase database and storage, I am reading too much about firebase admin sdk, What is the basic difference between normal firebase services and firebase admin sdk or is it one and the same, also if i am starting development now is using firebase admin sdk recommended...?

Also i will integrate the database and storage to my android application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll add on to what Doug said in his answer, I suspect you might be confusing the front-end Firebase packages with back-end admin packages.

- If you are going to have the client interact with Firebase, you'll need to use front-end packages. Depending on the platform your front-end is being presented on (*Web, iOS, Android, etc...*) there are different options to suit your platform... web=`JavaScript SDK`... ios=`ios SDK`... etc...
- The Admin SDKs allow you to add back-end functionality. Because there are so many different languages that can be used on the back-end, there are many flavors of the Admin SDK.

[This release-notes page](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) does a good job demonstrating the many "Firebase" packages available... both front-end and back-end.

Comment: From what u said the admin sdk can be used for an api and the firebase front end packages for android app. What do you suggest i use for a web application using html as front end and python for its communication with the database?

Comment: Web browsers only understand JavaScript, so your web-based front-end would have to use the JavaScript SDK. Android apps only understand the Android SDK... and the backend, regardless of what front-end platform you choose... can be Python/Java/Node/.NET/Go, your choice of whichever language's Admin SDK - and yes, the Admin SDKs can be used to create an API.

Answer (score 3):

If you're writing code with python and you want to access Firebase and Cloud serivces, the recommended option is to use the admin SDK.  It's designed to be the easiest way to read and write data in your database, upload and download files to your Cloud Storage buckets, and perform other administrative functions, such as authenticated user management.

I'm not sure what you mean by "normal Firebase services".

Answer (score 2):

Python Firebase admin SDK: If you use Firebase Admin SDK then you can have admin access to things without worrying about restrictions and rules on your database.

Python Firebase: If you use python firebase (normal firebase) then you need to authenticate each time you access your data (Means you can set rules and permissions for your document)