# How firebase Admin SDK differs from firebase console web page?

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

I'm developing an android app with firebase as a backend and I heard a word named **Admin SDK**. I had searched for it and found it is used to manage data.

But I have a doubt that firebase provides a console webpage (console.firebase.google.com) to manage data, but why there is a separate Admin SDK?

Can someOne please explain...

Comment: Have you check this answer? [Difference between normal firebase and firebase admin sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52190544/difference-between-normal-firebase-and-firebase-admin-sdk). Firebase Admin SDK's [setup page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) also explains what can it be used for.

Comment: I had seen those before adding this question. But those answers are not satisfying.

Comment: If there was a specific use case of your application then I guess it would be easier to explain imo..

Answer (score 2):

The firebase admin SDK provides a simple and easy way to modify firebase settings and data using API calls.

For example, you might ask: why should you even have a regular SDK to store data? After all, you can store and save data directly from the web interface. It is, however, simply not secure or practical to have users update their own data each time using the console.

Similarly, the admin SDK is just like the regular SDK but with administrator permissions. For example, it allows you to bypass the rules set up using your firestore rules. The Firebase admin SDK is meant to be used on your backend - so you know it is running trusted software. You know that it will act the way you expect it to, unlike code running client-side that can't be trusted.

For example, let's say that you want to be able to delete a user's post if certain conditions are met. The user will make the request to your server, and it will check if the conditions are met, and then delete the post using its admin privilages. Sure you could technically automate this using firestorm rules, but those can be quite cumbersome and might not work in more complicated examples.

You can also even use it to integrate with other applications like connecting your app to a moderation tool or a curse detector that can't or shouldn't run on the client's device.

Comment: Can we create an Android app with admin SDK for personal use of admin to manage data?

Comment: I don't see why not, the official admin SDK supports Java - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin#java.

Answer (score 1):

Is your question is *why does Admin SDK exists?*

- There are several administrative tasks such as deleting users, listing collections and many more which the client cannot and should not be able to do.
- Firebase Admin SDK has *admin* access to your Firebase project's resources.
- It does not obey any security rules and can read/write any of your database, storage bucket..

That is why you must use Admin SDK in a server (or cloud function only). Although I feel Firebase Admin SDK is more useful if you use your own servers and authentication method. If you are using a custom server then:

- It can be used to generate [custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) so you can authenticate users using your own method (maybe legacy auth system) but still use Firebase Authentication to handle the auth tokens thereafter.
- If you use your own database (and not any from Firebase), the Admin SDK can [verify the ID Token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) sent by client and get identity of that user. Thereafter it's could be a simple if-else statement for you to decide if the user has access to the request resource or not.